# Efficient Proof for all cases of triangle inequality

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, real-numbers, triangle-inequality

The question asks Find an efficient proof for all the cases at once by first demonstrating

$$
(a+b)^2 \leq (|a|+|b|)^2
$$

My attempt at the proof:

for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$

$$
\begin{align*}
|a+b|^2 =&(a+b)^2 \text{ (Since $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, $x^2=|x|^2$)}\\
 =& a^2+2ab+b^2\\
 \leq&|a|^2+2|a||b|+|b|^2 \text{( Since $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}, x\leq |x|$)}\\
=&(|a| +|b|)^2 
\end{align*}
$$

But this is where I get stuck, I can arrive at the inequality but I do not know how to continue you from here. The question states that this should be efficient proof for all the cases, but jumping from that step to $|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$ seems like a big jump with some steps missing. Any push in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for positive numbers $a$ and $b$, $$a^2 \le b^2 \implies a\le b $$
Thus $$|a+b|^2 \le (|a|+|b|)^2 \implies |a+b|\le|a|+|b|$$

Comment: But how do we know $a$ and $b$ are positive?

Comment: We do not need $a$ or $b$ to be positive, but we know that $|a+b|$ is positive

Comment: Of course! Thank you! I really appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to say is that if $0<r^2<s^2$, then $r<s$. This follows from the fact that $r\geq s>0$ implies $r^2\geq s^2$.

Also, you are missing a square on $|a|$, and your last $\leq$ should be $=$.